# Displaying time and date next to part of the ping output

Tags: linux, shell-script, date, ping

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $7}'
date
```

So for the code above, I want it to display the date and time in this format below

```
Tue May 5 11:11:11 UTC 2020  time=0.838 ms
```

So far it prints this output

```
data.
time=1.24
packet
Tue May  5 23:31:33 UTC 2020
```

I want time=1.24 next to the UTC 2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | awk -v date="$(date)" '$7 ~ /^time/{ print date, $7, $8 }'
```

This saves the output of the `date` command substitution in awk variable `date` and prints the date and the 7th and 8th field only if the 7th field begins with `time`.

Answer (score 0):

This should appear if the manner specified.

```
echo -n "$(date) "
ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | awk '$7 ~ /^time=/ {print $7}'
```

Not entirely clear if you want the units field as your post has conflicting samples. If you do, change the end like so `print $7,$8`

Comment: where is the time=1.24s

Comment: I get this output

Comment: Tue May  5 23:43:15 UTC 2020 [root@lab-12 ~]#

Comment: Sorry should be fixed I think

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$(date)  time=$(ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | awk '/transmitted/{print $NF}')"
```

the phrase $( .... ) means run command that is inside the brackets and insert output here.

The ping command is as per other suggestions but the output is filtered slightly differently - this is the output of just the ping...

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=22.9 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.919/22.919/22.919/0.000 ms
```

The awk command seaches for the line matching /transmitted/ and then prints the last value in the line, in this case the time value. Because the number of words in the line can vary depending on the 'ping' implementation or output etc... we use NF to always pick the last element of the line.